# Conversion from int to byte forcibly results in --- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, network-programming, arrays, numberformatexception

I was writing a program to convert a String fed IP-Address to IP-Address by utilising the method `InetAddress.getByAddress(byte[] addr)`.

So, what I did was input IP-from the user in the form of String. Parsed it and splitted the IP on . using `String.split("\\.")`.

Then, I started converting that String array into byte array where I am right now stuck on.

Please help me to get rid of this situation. Any workaround OR alternate way of accessing this will be heartly appreciated...

**The code goes as :-**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        System.out.println("Enter the IP-Address whose MAC-address you wanna know :-");
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        String ipa=s.nextLine();
        String ba[]=ipa.split("\\.");
        for(String ap:ba){
            System.out.println("Given IP="+ap);
        }
        byte [] bad=new byte[ba.length]; 
        for(int i=0;i<ba.length;i++){
            System.out.println("Ba-"+i+"="+ba[i]);
        if(Integer.valueOf(ba[i])>127){
            int temp=Integer.valueOf(ba[i]);
            //System.out.println("Value of "+i+"---"+temp);
            bad[i]=(byte) temp;    // this produces error at run-time
        }
            bad[i]=Byte.valueOf(ba[i]);
            System.out.println("Bad-"+i+"="+bad[i]);
        }
        //byte bad[]={(byte)192,(byte)168,122,1};
        InetAddress ia=InetAddress.getByAddress(bad);
        ...............  here is the rest of code and it compiles well.
```

**Exception thrown :-**

```
Enter the IP-Address whose MAC-address you wanna know :-
192.168.122.1
Given IP=192
Given IP=168
Given IP=122
Given IP=1
Ba-0=192

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range.   Value:"192" Radix:10
at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Byte.java:151)
at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Byte.java:205)
at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Byte.java:231)
at NP_7.main(NP_7.java:36)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: May I know who downvoted the question as I didn't get the exact solution what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save yourself from all this trouble if you use [`InetAddress.getByName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName-java.lang.String-) instead.

You get the error because the range of byte is from -128 to 127, so for example 192 is out of range.

You can fix the code by changing the loop that fills `bad` into this:

```
    for(int i=0;i<ba.length;i++){
        System.out.println("Ba-"+i+"="+ba[i]);
        bad[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(ba[i]);
    }
```

Comment: `getByName` accepts IP addresses, not just host names.

Comment: Well if you really have to parse the IP address yourself, the code is not hard to fix, see the update...

Comment: It again is throwing the exception---incomaptible types,`Integer` cannot be converted to `byte`. Your code is though incorrect and non-compilable ,but, your suggestion has helped me! So,I am accepting your answer. Please remove the `fixing code section` so that I could upvote and accept the answer...

Comment: Are you sure your code is exactly what I posted? The parseInt method returns a primitive int, not an Integer object, so I don't see how you could get that error.

Comment: I am confused a lot,so please consider this statement meaningful,actually, it started giving the question's original exception again when I followed your code's advice by doing this---`bad[i]=(byte)Integer.parseInt(ba[i]);`

Comment: Nonetheless, you just edit/remove that from your answer so that your answer becomes valuable for some third-person visiting this page.

Comment: Heyy, I already mentioned that your solution is not workable and it again throws that error,please undo your edit! It is same as that in my program! Check that please...

Comment: There is no error in the code in the answer. If it does not work for you the problem is somewhere else.