# How to parse a proxy socks packet in java?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming

Im trying to build a basic proxy 4 server, and I have to parse a packet and extract its informations that looks like this:

```
1 byte (version)
1 byte (command)
2 byte (port)
4 byte (ip)
X byte (userID, builds a string by looping until '\0' is found)
```

Here's my code so far:

```
InputStream reader = socket.getInputStream();

byte[] ver  = new byte[1];
byte[] cmd  = new byte[1];
byte[] port = new byte[2];
byte[] ip   = new byte[4];

reader.read(ver, 0, 1);  //should be: 4
reader.read(cmd, 1, 1);  //should be: 1
reader.read(port, 2, 2); //should be: 00, 80
reader.read(ip, 4, 4);   //should be: 217, 70, 182, 162
```

Here's the response I get from my code:  `[4, 1, 0, 80, -39, 70, -74, -94]`

For some reason the IP part I get is always wrong, I really don't know why. My second issue would be: Is there an easy and clean way to get the last userID string part, without having to build a messy loop that could end up hanging for ever, if the `\0` byte was not found?

Comment: could you dump the `Stream` data `byte`-by-`byte` to see what it contains?

Comment: @BoristheSpider: [4, 1, 0, 80, -39, 70, -74, -94, 0, 0] (without userID)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throw it all away and use the methods of `DataInputStream`. They will give you ints, shorts, longs, and fully-read  byte arrays, and take care of network byte ordering for you as well.

Comment: Thank you. I will give `DataInputStream` a try and a bit of research and get back to you.

Comment: I agree that it is the general trend and is used nowadays! But,please don't introduce terms only,always leave some examples. You might yourself receive downvotes for this!

Comment: @shekharsuman Don't put words into my mouth. I didn't say anything about 'general trends', and this solution has been used in Java since 1996, not just 'nowadays'. And I expect any competent computer programmer to be able to devise a correct solution based on this information.

Comment: This solved my issue, it's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! As for the negative IP values I had to convert them to int as shekhar suggested, but using `DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte`.

Comment: @shekharsuman I am not guessing about this. I was using it in 1997. Check your facts. `DataInputStream` is marked `@since 1.0`, which is 1996. And don't make personal remarks here.

Comment: @EJP-Soory if I have hurted you through my words. I am pretty inexperienced in front of you as I am still a student of 20 and still learning. But,what I quoted was just to help OP about his issue. I appreciate your answer and now even +1'ing this. Please forgive me if I have hurted you through comments OR through indirect remarks. But,I believe neither I did that, and nor it was my intention...

Answer (score 2):

The first issue which you received is all because of byte-overflow and hence,turning to negative numbers as byte ranges from -128 to 127 in Java.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949268/conversion-from-int-to-byte-forcibly-results-in-exception-in-thread-main-j) which I asked on this forum to know about the magic(issues) of byte[]...

Seriously,if this is your approach for last-field,(ip)---I am sure you're not going to get correct answer using direct reforms on byte. The possible solution seems to use other approach like storing in temporary int[], like

```
int[] ip   = new int[4];
byte[] temp = new byte[4];
reader.read(temp, 4, 4);   //should be: 217, 70, 182, 162
for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
{
 if(temp[i]<0)
 ip[i]=(int)(256+temp[i]);  // careful here
 else
 ip[i]=(int)temp[i];
}
```

And,for the second issue,I think that better solution is get length of String-part using `String.length()`.

```
 int len = userID.length();  // assume user-id would be String type
 userid = new byte[len];   // notice the difference between userid and userID
 reader.read(userid,0,len);
 // I am confused as to how are you reading input from user,
 // if you clarify further,I'll update my answer...
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give `int[]` a try and get back to you. As for the second part of my question, the userID string is something the proxy clients set for themselves. I have no way of telling what size they are except by waiting for the `\0` byte.

Comment: It is utterly impossible to write correct network code while ignoring the value returned by the `read()` method.

Comment: @shekhar suman: Please ask if you need more clarification. And sorry it wasn't me who downvoted you.

Comment: @shekarsuman If that comment about 'workarounds' is addressed to me, it is nonsense.

Comment: SORRY @EJP if that hurted you. But,why you playing so rude. I appreciated your hint below your answer.